# req.body is undefined - React & Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

This is my first time using react and node js. So for react, I have this form:

```
<form onSubmit={register}>
   <label>First Name: </label>
   <input required type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" onChange={formValues}>
```

So here is what I wrote for the onChange function to update my hook

```
const formValues = (event) => {
        setUserDetails({
            ...userDetails,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    }
```

This is how I wrote my hook

```
    const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState({
        firstName: ''
    });
```

For the onSubmit, this is how I wrote it

```
const register = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const body = JSON.stringify({
            firstName: userDetails.firstName
        });
        const response = await axios.post("/auth/register", body, {
            header: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
    }
```

Finally, when I try to console.log

```
console.log("the request body: ", req.body);
console.log("the first name", req.body.firstName);
```

Here are the results:

```
the request body:  [Object: null prototype] {'{"firstName":"dawd"}': ''}

the first name undefined
```

This is confusing to me since I have the value for "req.body" but when I tried to get the value for the first name I get an undefined.

In my app.js which is my server, I have body-parser and it is still doesn't seem to fix the issue

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require("express"); // Start server from nodejs

const app = express();

// Using body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: axios post does not require stringify, so your body can be `{ firstName: userDetails.firstName }`

Comment: Thank you Thanh, that actually fixes the error. Thank you so much

Comment: I added it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `fetch`, `axios` takes an object as body as pointed out by @Thanh. So when you convert your body into a string with `JSON.stringify`, axios converts it back into an object by taking the string and using it as the object's key, hence `{'{"firstName":"dawd"}': ''}`. You should pass an object directly into axios for it to be recived properly on the server side. So your `register` function should look like this:

```
   const register = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const body = {firstName: userDetails.firstName};
        const response = await axios.post("/auth/register", body, {
            header: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you codemonkey, you explanation is superb.

Comment: @ThinhPham No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer that fixed your problem by checking the green check box next to it.

Answer (score 0):

While passing the data to axios you donot need to use JSON.stringify. You can directly pass the data as object.

```
const body = {
        firstName: userDetails.firstName
    };
```

Comment: Thank you Zealous Web, That fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

axios post does not require stringify, so your body can be `{ firstName: userDetails.firstName }`